# Refresh dataset after a given time and update the label + SQL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, label

So i have a stored procedure that gives the amount of units packed per hour, So when a unit is passed, this is updated in my table.. i need to pass the amount packed minute by minute to the label.. And once a given period has passed the label should refresh back to 0... So the hours are 6am-2pm - 2pm - 10pm - 10pm - 6pm..

I am not sure how to update the label with my stored procedure..

I think i may need to do a calculation on my stored proc? and return that to my label? I am a bit lost on this...

https://ibb.co/jOEkfy

The screenshot is my stored proc.. now i need to know how i can update my label with these results and then it resets after 8 hours... this is my c# code so far.

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Refreshdata(214, DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddMinutes(-1));
                BindDropDownList();

```
        }
    }

    private void BindDropDownList()
    {
        BizManager mgr = new BizManager();

        DataView dv = mgr.GetItemSeriesMaster().DefaultView; //how to filter data
        dv.RowFilter = ProductQueryFilter;
        Dropdownlist1.DataSource = dv;

        Dropdownlist1.DataTextField = "Description"; // the items to be displayed in the list items
        Dropdownlist1.DataValueField = "Id"; // the id of the items displayed
        Dropdownlist1.DataBind();

    }

    private string ProductQueryFilter
    {
        get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProductQueryFilter"]; }
    }


    public void Refreshdata(int selectedProduct, DateTime shiftStart, DateTime shiftEnd)
    {
        BizManager biz = new BizManager();

        GridView1.DataSource = biz.GetPacktstatisticsForShift(
            shiftStart
            , shiftEnd
            , selectedProduct).DefaultView;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    public void Dropdownlist1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime shiftStart = DateTime.Today;
        DateTime shiftEnd = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddMinutes(-1);
        int productId;
        if (int.TryParse(Dropdownlist1.SelectedValue, out productId))
            Refreshdata(productId, shiftStart, shiftEnd);
    }
```

Stored Proc

USE [Production]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[uspGetPackStatisticsPerShift]    Script Date: 29/05/2018 13:07:04 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROC [dbo].[uspGetPackStatisticsPerShift]

```
@ShiftStart DateTime,
@ShiftEnd DateTime,
@SeriesMasterId int
```

AS

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

--DECLARE @LogicalMachineId int
--DECLARE @WorkCellId int

--SELECT @LogicalMachineId = mr.LogicalMachineId, @WorkCellId = lm.WorkCellId
--FROM Shared.dbo.MachineRegistry mr
--INNER JOIN Shared.dbo.LogicalMachine lm on lm.Id = mr.LogicalMachineId and lm.Active=1
--WHERE mr.Active=1 AND mr.SystemId = 'Generic' AND mr.DnsName = @MachineName 


--if (@WorkCellId is null)
--BEGIN
--  RAISERROR('uspGetBuildStatisticsPerShift() Workstation not defined',15,1)
--  RETURN
--END


-- Now get the data

select  DateDiff(hour, @ShiftStart, psh.DtTmEnd) + 1  AS ShiftHour
    , ifsm.[Id] as FrameSizeMasterId
    , Count(ph.Id ) as TotalPacked
from Production.dbo.PackHistory ph
INNER JOIN Production.dbo.PackStageHistory psh on psh.PackHistoryId = ph.Id AND psh.PackScheduleStageID=2
INNER JOIN Production.dbo.ItemSerialNumber isn on isn.Id = ph.ItemSerialNumberId
INNER JOIN Production.dbo.ItemMaster im on im.Id = isn.ItemMasterId
INNER JOIN Production.dbo.ItemSeriesMaster ism on ism.Id = im.SeriesMasterId AND im.SeriesMasterId =  @SeriesMasterId
INNER JOIN Production.dbo.ItemFrameSizeMaster ifsm on ifsm.Id = im.FrameSizeMasterId
where psh.DtTmEnd BETWEEN @ShiftStart AND @ShiftEnd AND psh.Successful = 1 AND psh.ReRun=0
group by  DateDiff(hour, @ShiftStart, psh.DtTmEnd) + 1 , ifsm.[Id]   
order by 1
```

Comment: You need to share C# code and sql query and also explain what exact issue you are facing

Comment: I have not added a label in my code behind just yet. Not sure what i need to input.

Comment: One quick way is using an update panel and and ajax timer, check the msdn doc on the timer and adapt it to your needs https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386404(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: The screen capture of stored procedure is not clearly visible. Also c# code is just binding grid view and dropdownlist. Which part of it is calling stored procedure?

Comment: The stored proc is being called from the business class. this already updates my gridview but i need it to update my label also..  and then refresh after 8 hours.. and the label needs to increment by one.. i can refresh the page so it gets the updated figures but not sure how to pass the stored procedure to the label and have it increment by one instead of having the rest of the data showing.